# How to make navbar toggle using bootstra?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Navbar Toggle is not working with Bootstrap 5.2. The hamburger button shows correctly when screen is small but when I click on button the nav items don't appare. Any suggestion?

`

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Tech Blog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"/>
</body>
```

`

```
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Tech Blog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

just change script to this

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Kevin, thank you for the help. Your suggestion worked